# Populate SQL query with blank rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

(This is a general SQL question, but I am specifically using MSAccess 2010 so looking for how to do this with Access' flavor of SQL)

I have a table called `offices` which has `id`, `office_name`, `num_desks`.

Another table called `employees` which has `id`, `employee_name`.

And a final table called `employee_offices` which has `id`, `office_id`, `employee_id`.

I can assign employees to offices via `employee_offices`.

I am trying to generate a report which shows all offices and the employees assigned to the, but also includes blank lines for any empty desks in that office.

I realize a "simple" way to do this would be to create a `desks` table with `id`, `office_id`, delete the `num_desks` column from the `offices` table and change `employee_offices` to something like `employee_desks`. Then my report  would be a simple `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and it would include all the unassigned desks. However for the sake of sanity (in this case, there is no contextual difference between desks), I am not going to do this. Plus if I start deleting desks I have referential constraints to deal with (which obviously exist for a good reason and would catch the fact that I am leaving employees without a desk), but I just want to be able to change the number of desks.

I can calculate the number of empty desks (or lack of desks) through the following command:

```sql
    SELECT
        office_id,
        num_desks - num_employees AS desk_diff,
        MAX(0, num_desks - num_employees) AS blank_rows_to_add
    FROM offices LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT office_id, COUNT(employee_id) AS num_employees
        FROM employee_offices 
        GROUP BY office_Id
    ) AS num_employees_by_office ON offices.id = num_employees_by_office.office_id
```

Is there a way to take this number (`blank_rows_to_add`) and somehow utilze it to add that many blank rows (or at least the row only has the `office_id`/`office_name`) to a report showing a list of employees by office? I know this can be done with VBA but I am specifically looking for an SQL method that also doesn't include a temp table if at all possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Look up *SQL number table*, this is usually the way to go for this sort of requirement. Note that this is not a temp table, but a constant one. If this doesn't help, please add some sample data. [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add blank lines to complete an Access report so that it matches a printed form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410123/how-to-add-blank-lines-to-complete-an-access-report-so-that-it-matches-a-printed)